# Firefox Addon: Add some functions and object to the window object

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I just started using the FireFox Builder to build a simple addon. I realised that I cannot get direct access to the window object.

What I want to do is to get the window object and pollute it with some classes and functions so I can call them from the page itself.

Below is the current code:

```js
// This is an active module of the ritcoder Add-on
require("widget").Widget({
    id: "widgetID1",
    label: "My Mozilla Widget",
    contentURL: "http://www.mozilla.org/favicon.ico",
    onClick: function(evt){
        var tabs = require("tabs");
        var activeTab = tabs.activeTab;

        var notifications = require("notifications");
        notifications.notify({
          title: "Jabberwocky",
          text: "'Twas brillig, and the slithy toves",
          data: "did gyre and gimble in the wabe",
          onClick: function (data) {
            console.log(data);
            // console.log(this.data) would produce the same result.
          }
        });

        activeTab.window.a=20; //this fails
        context.alert('yesx');
    }
});
```

How do I do this? Inject some code into the active page so that it can be called.

regards,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use [tab.attach()](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/1.2/packages/addon-kit/docs/tabs.html#attach%28options%29) to run a content script in the tab's context, and then use [unsafeWindow](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/1.2/dev-guide/addon-development/content-scripts/access.html) to add properties the page's script can see. (You should also read the introduction to [Content Scripts](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/1.2/dev-guide/addon-development/web-content.html).)

The Addon SDK doesn't provide a direct access (without the content script) to the page from the add-on's code because it tries to be forward compatible with the plans to make web pages run in processes separate from the browser's and the add-on's process.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. I had to use the unsafeWindow though to be able to add things to the window object. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks, after searching far and wide for a way to access an opened tab's window object, this is the one thing that finally worked. Note that `unsafeWindow` is a top-level var in the content script, not a sub-object of anything.